# Convert markdown to HTML in Astro

Tags: markdown, astrojs

How can I convert markdown to HTML within Astro? If you import an MD file within Astro, the content will [automatically be converted](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/) to HTML in the background.

But I use Strapi as my CMS system. I fetch my posts with the [fetch() method](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/data-fetching/), and that works fine. However, the content is in markdown format, and I want to convert it to HTML.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Astro documentation suggests [using the `marked` package to render remotely fetched Markdown](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#fetching-remote-markdown):

```
---
import { marked } from 'marked';
const response = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/adam-p/markdown-here/Markdown-Cheatsheet.md');
const markdown = await response.text();
const content = marked.parse(markdown);
---
<article set:html={content} />
```

The [`astro-remote` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/astro-remote) also offers components that do something similar while the [`@astropub/md` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@astropub/md) will render Markdown for you using the remark ecosystem and can use your existing Astro Markdown configuration if you want it to.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me in the right direction.